# How abstract is Objective-C compared to Lisp?

Tags: objective-c, lisp

I am coming from Lisp and wish to develop an Iphone app. I was hoping to hear from other lisp or python developes on how Objective-c compares to Lisp in terms of abstractions, such as closures, first class functions, macros, etc.

Comment: please re-read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this type of question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Mat, I think this question is not subjective, clearly defined, and helpful.  I just wish the title wasn't couched in terms of "rating" Objective-C.  But a survey of language features and differences with respect to another language seems reasonable.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: the title and phrasing are what made me post the above comment - too "open-ended", "discussion" type question. "What should I keep in mind wrt the implementation of closures in Objective-C, coming from a Lisp background" (or something to that effect) does indeed sound like a good question though. Good thing the "close" feature requires that many votes I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have amended the title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objective-C has its history rooted in SmallTalk, and as a consequence, like Lisp, a lot of what makes the language useful exists in functions (in this case, methods of classes) that you can override at runtime with your own code and can add functions at runtime to classes.  But, in Objective-C the underlying C is never very far away, so unlike in Lisp you do have to worry about things like memory management and the language is obviously more procedural than functional.

Recently Objective-C compilers added support for "blocks", i.e. closures.

Of course, Objective-C is still a compiled language and everything that gives it features you would expect to find in Lisp, Python, or SmallTalk is built on top of that.  I might get some down votes for it, but given your background I think you'll find Objective-C to be about the nearest thing to developing in a fully dynamic, interpreted language that you can get right now while with a compiled language.

Just in case you haven't checked or someone coming along later to read this question needs it, have a look at [the Wikipedia section on Objective-C syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Syntax).

As a P.S., depending on what you're doing you might also be interested in tools like PhoneGap that let you develop for iPhone (and other mobile platforms) in JavaScript, since JavaScript, despite its name and C-like syntax, has a lot of the power you are used to having in Lisp.

Comment: wow, I never knew it was based on smalltalk. I'm going to check objective-c out more. Thanks

Comment: and I'll check out phone gap too

Comment: +1, with a minor nit to pick. Yes, Objective-C (on iOS at least) does not have GC, but in practice I spend very little time worrying about memory management. Basically, the only thinking I have to do is deciding whether to declare a property as `retain` or `copy` - not very worrisome. :-)

Comment: If you'd rather stay with Lisp when developing for iPhone, consider joining the [ECL on iOS](https://github.com/TerjeNorderhaug/ecl-iphone-builder/) project:

Comment: are there any example apps of this ECL on IOS project?

Comment: you can also check https://github.com/nulang/nu which is a lispy scripting language that generates objective-c taking advantage of all of objective-c with some ruby influence. Also you can try React.Native with clojurescript